# How do we assign id to react component who are rendered using loop

Tags: reactjs

I have build my website using react. I have import a new library for other features the issue is that the new library used id and I have not assigned id to tags since all are rendered using a loop. Changing the code to give id to all tag is difficult since the code is spread across multiple files. What can I do in that case?

I have tried give id using this "uniqueid" library but it is really difficult to do.

I want a way in which all tags get a unique id.

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420835/how-to-generate-unique-ids-for-form-labels-in-react

Comment: I read it but it uses a library uuid to generate it. But each time the page is loaded the id would be different I can't use it in my code to get the element. please correct me if  i am wrong. And it would be better if it can be done without any extra library. I searched the web but it told that it is a bad idea to keep a global counter.

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you are facing.