# React : to assign the dynamic ids to the button/tr so that i can open form for the selecetd rows only

Tags: reactjs

I want to assign the packages i.e. selected by the user but it is displaying form in all the trs.

```
    // Binding of showForm()
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.showForm = this.showForm.bind(this); // bind of show function
       
        this.state = {
          packages: [],
      showForm: false
        };
        
      }
    // UI  for showForm : to be displayed after handling on click
    showForm = () => {
            return (
              <div>
          
     <form  >

 </form>
    </div>
              );
          }
    
    // table : displaying data coming from firebase had been implemented
     <tbody>``
          ...
            <tr key={pack.uid}   onClick={() => this.setState({showForm: true}) } >  // chnging state                  
               <td> 
                   <button type="button" value = {pack.name}  className="btn btn-secondary">
                       Assign
                   </button>
                   {this.state.showForm ? this.showForm() : null} // maintaiing state
               </td>
             
             </tr>
            ))}``
          </tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate unique IDs for form labels in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420835/how-to-generate-unique-ids-for-form-labels-in-react)

Comment: I tidied up a bit, but please read [ask]. This isn't very clear.