# React useId creates invalid selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to get the element by id. (It's an example code to reproduce the error)

```
function MyComponent(){
  const myId = useId();

  useEffect(() => {
    const myComponentDOMElement = document.querySelector(`#${myId}`); // error here
    }
  )

  return <div id={ myId }> text </div>
}
```

This code gives an error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#:Rt6m:' is not a valid selector.
```

useRef couldn't help me in my case. How can I use the ID to get the element.

Comment: why would `useRef` couldn't help  just curious ...

Comment: Thanks for asking, TIL something new about `querySelector` 

Comment: @KcH I was making a custom Select component. To close it onClick somewhere else I was adding an event listener to `document.body`. To check if I clicked outside the select I was checking if `event.target` has a parent which is opened select. I used `Element.closest` which accepts string selector. `.closest` method works the same way as the `querySelector`, so I simplified the question.

Answer (score 20):

The IDs generated by React's `useId` are surrounded by colons (for example `:R1ab6km:`) and these special characters get interpreted by `querySelector`. You can escape them using `CSS.escape()` so that `querySelector` treats those characters literally.

```js
document.querySelector(`#${CSS.escape(id)}`)
```

Answer (score 6):

I figured out that I can use the attribute selector.

```
function MyComponent(){
  const myId = useId();

  useEffect(() => {
    const myComponentDOMElement = document.querySelector(`[id="${myId}"]`); // this will work
    }
  )
  return <div id={ myId }> text </div>
}
```